# Axios.post then method doesn't run

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

I'm running an Axios post request in a React app. The `then` method doesn't run at all. How can I get it to run after the axios post?

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:81/login", {
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response, "response")
    props.login()
    props.close()
})
```

Comment: Perhaps your request gets an error, so you need a `.catch` to see the error. Also, your `.then` function has two consecutive `return` statements. The second one won't work.

Comment: as Ron B. said - a second return will never be executed. In programming - whenever a code reaches 'return' then it returns whatever you provide and the rest of the code is stopped from executing (in simple words). So `props.close()` will never be executed in this case. And the rest Ron B. said is also true. Just wanted to add on an explanation to why `props.close()` will never executed just in case :)

Comment: I tried using a catch method and that didn't run either

Comment: @chackerian Have you solved this because I have the same issue as well

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others in the comments, you need to handle the errors with `.catch()`.

I recreated a working example using code as close to yours as possible :

```js
export default function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {

    Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", {
      email: "some email",
      password: "some password"
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response, "response");
      setResponse(response.data.title);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      setResponse("This is an error from catch()");
    });

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{response}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit wispy-cookies-0gvmqe]

Edit the **API link** to an **invalid one** and you can see the error is being handled correctly by the `.catch()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tested `then()` and it doesn't run, and in a comment you mentioned you tried `catch()` and it doesn't run either, you might want to look at the code in your post endpoint (i.e. `http://localhost:81/login`). If that code never sends an HTTP response, that would be why your `then()` function is not getting called. With no HTTP response, the promise for Axios post call is never completed.